# How to show last data with created date?

Tags: php

I have a problem to show one of duplicate data with last created date. This is is my query :

```
 $sqlpur ="SELECT DISTINCT pn, created_date, id_purchase FROM pur_supp ORDER BY pn, created_date DESC";
```

**This is the result.**
[image]

**This is a data from database.**
[image]

But, I want to show just one of duplicate data. an example just to show 02N64073 with last created Date.

Comment: have you tried `group`ing them using the column that you provided above?

Comment: @Ghost, at the first time I using Distinct of this duplicate date but when I'm confused to show pn with last created date